# react component can't wait for scrape data

Tags: reactjs

I am developing some service that **scrapes** some data from one site.(function getLinks() add required data to global array results1[] and it works fine)
After that I want to render this this data using React Component.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    getLink();
    super(props);
    this.content = results1[1];
  }
```

But constructor doesn't wait when the data is ready. I have tried different methods for resolving this issue. Please anyone who faces with same problems. Help me

Answer (score 1):

Web scraping is asynchronous in JavaScript, you should add a callback for when the server returns the data or preferrably, use promises. Example with fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: "data fetching" is not necessarily asynchronous in Javascript or any other language (though your example of the fetch library is, and site-scraping like the OP wants to do almost certainly will be too).

Comment: Edited my post to clarify.